# Awk and Grep to get data from CLI

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to get output as below:

```
Number      Name         Value
*************************************
889900     Staff         256000
990088     Staff         1048576
```

And my input would be as below:

```
%%LST:="889900";%%


Actual                            Service                           Key                              Value 
Staff                             00000001                          350                               256000        
company                           00000002                          360                               1572864       

Total count = 2

There is together 1 report


%%LST:="990088";%%


Actual                            Service                           Key                               Value 
Staff                             00000003                          350                               1048576       
plusmines                         00000004                          120                               20480         
different                         1001                              201                               5120          

Total count = 3

There is together 1 report


%%LST:="112233";%%


Actual                            Service                           Key                               Value 
additional                        00000005                          320                               1048576       
payitoff                          20001                             73710                             1048576       
clubonetwothree                   00000006                          90006280                          1048576       

Total count = 3

There is together 1 report
```

I have done below coding:

```
IFS=$'\n'
cat > initial
cat initial | grep "%%LST:=" | awk -F'"' '{print$2}' > x1
cat initial | awk -F' ' '{if ($3 == 350) print $1,$4; else echo "0"}' > x2
rm results2
echo -e "Number       Name                      Value\n*************************************" >> results2
paste x1      x2 | sort -n | expand -t 13 >> results2
cat results2; 
rm initial
```

What i want is to get `"Number"` from the `"%%LST:="` in the input and the name to be from if `"Key"` is equals=`350` and the `"Value"` is the corresponding value from the `"Key"` output.

Currently my coding is just getting all the `"Number"` and paste it in a list, together with grabbed info of `"Key"` and `"Value"`.

The problem with this is, if my record don't have `"Key" = 350` it doesn't skip or leave an empty space. My whole final result is going awry.

What function can I use to only list out related information that have `"Key = 350"` ?

Comment: is the line `%%LST:"112233";%%` correct?  or is it supposed to be `%%LST:=` ?

Comment: it is supposed to be `%%LST:="112233";%%`. sorry, i have amended it.

Comment: doesn't matter, i wrote my awk script so that it would work either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```awk
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    OFS="\t";
    print "Number","Name","Value";
    print "*************************************";
    number="" ; name="" ; value="";
};

/^%%LST/ {
    if (number != "" && name != "" && value != "") { 
        print number, name, value;
        name=""; value="";
    } ;
    number=gensub(/%%LST:=?"([0-9]+)";%%/,"\\1","g") 
} ;

$3 == 350 { 
   name=$1;
   value=$4
};

END {
    if (name != "") {
        print number, name, value
    }
}
```

Save this as, e.g., `remy.awk`, make it executable with `chmod +x remy.awk`, and give it data on stdin or a filename (e.g. `./remy.awk remy.txt`)

The `BEGIN {}` section sets up the Output Field Separator (OFS) to be a tab, then prints the output headers, and initialises the `number`, `name`, and `value` variables.

Then it extracts the number (into a variable called `number`) from lines beginning with '%%LST' but first it checks if `number` was non-empty - if it already had a value then it prints out the details for the previous record, and clears the `name` and `value` variables.

On lines where the key (field 3) is equal to 350, it extracts the `name` and `value` from the line.

Finally, the `END {}` block prints the variables if `name` is non-empty, so that it works correctly if the final record (delimited by %%LST lines) is one with Key==350.  Without this, it would fail to print the data from the final record.

Output, given your sample data above, is:

```
$ ./remy.awk remy.txt 
Number  Name    Value
*************************************
889900  Staff   256000
990088  Staff   1048576
```

Comment: Hey @cas, would it be too much if i asked, is there anyway i can sort out the list by value, highest to lowest?

Comment: pipe the output through `sort -r -n -k 3`...but get rid of the header lines first with, e.g., `| sed '1,2d'` (you may have noticed that many unix tools don't print headers like this.  That's so there's no extraneous crap that needs to be removed before it can be piped into other tools).  Alternatively, the script would have to be re-written so that it didn't print out the records as it found them.  Instead, it would have to add the records to an array, and then sort and print the array in the `END {}` block....but why do that, when there's a good `sort` utility that has many versatile options?

Comment: e.g. `./remy.awk remy.txt | sed -e '1,2d' | sort -r -n -k 3`.  Or edit the `remy.awk` script to delete or comment-out the header printing in the `BEGIN {}` block and you won't need the `sed -e '1,2d'` in the pipeline.

Comment: BTW, it's also worth noting that some of the tools that usually print header lines by default have options to suppress printing headers.  e.g. `ps` from `procps` has a `h` option (or `--no-headers`).